# Combining a string and a variable value to access an existing variable

Tags: css, list, sass

Imagine I have the following set of defined variables:

```
$sportmenu_1: #23765c;
$sportmenu_3: #5e6b34;
$sportmenu_4: #7d7e6c;
$sportmenu_6: #786857;
$sportmenu_8: #487a91;
```

I also have a list containing the "id" or the last digit of each variable as:

```
$list: 1 3 4 6 8;
```

I then want to the $sportmenu_ variables to both name the css selectors and populate the properties, I'm using a list and a foreach as follows:

```
@each $id in $list_id_sports {

  #sportmenu_#{$id} { //this works fine
    .menu-sport-item {
      background-color: #{$sportmenu_}#{$id}; //here's the issue!
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to combine a string and the $id from the foreach to generate a variable that the Sass compiler will understand. Basically, I want the foreach to create a new variable by combining `$sportmenu_` and the value of `$id`. Not sure if this is possible.

My solution doesn't work, since `$sportmenu_` doesn't exist. I've tried combining a string and the $id as: `"$sportmenu_"#{$id}` but this just creates a string followed by the value of $id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do something like this? Using maps

```
$list: (1: #23765c, 3: #5e6b34, 4: #7d7e6c, 6: #786857, 8: #487a91);

//$id grabs your map index, and $val grabs your hex color values
@each $id, $val in $list {
  #sportmenu_#{$id} {
    .menu-sport-item {
      background-color: #{$val};
    }
  }
}
```

You can try it out on [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/). Which outputs :

```
#sportmenu_1 .menu-sport-item {
  background-color: #23765c;
}

.....
```

All I am doing over here is nothing but using maps(kind of hash), looping over, and printing colors accordingly.

---

Also, what you were trying won't work. You are trying to interpolate two variables and trying to create a dynamic variable name on compile.

```
#{$sportmenu_}#{$id}; //will throw undefined $sprotsmenu_ error
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly the solution I ended up implementing, when I mean exactly is exaaactly haha. However, I'm still intrigued if there is a way to achieve what I wanted in the first place.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano As far as I know, there isn't any.

Comment: Cheers buddy, will accept your answer as accepted, solves the problem after all :)